# How to get value of some field in firebase firestore android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Like upper question, i want to get value of some field in firebase firestore instead of all document with **DocumentSnapshot**

like this in SQL `SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3 FROM table_name`

How can i do it?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Share us your database structure..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Cloud Firestore client-side SDKs always read and returns full documents. There is no way to read a subset of the fields in a document.

You can retrieve the entire document, and then process the `DocumentSnapshot` to just use the fields you're interested. But this means you're using more bandwidth than needed. If this is a regular occurrence for your app, consider creating a secondary collection where each document contains just the fields you're interested in.

Also see Doug's answer here (for Swift): [How to access a specific field from Cloud FireStore Firebase in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48312485/how-to-access-a-specific-field-from-cloud-firestore-firebase-in-swift)

Comment: yeah but this way I do not know what of a `DocumentSnapshot` has been modified!

Comment: @Frank Regarding the bandwidth issue you mentioned, If I query for a document with multiple sub-collections (/nested sub-collections), will firestore return the document along with the documents of the sub-collections ?

Comment: Firestore queries are shallow. They don't return documents from subcollections.

Answer (score 4):

Firestore can read single field value.
Firebase guides looks like didn't show these simple method.

For example:

```
[android]

String value = document.getString("col_1");


[node.js]

const value = doc.data().col_1
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike Yan it works. Really strange that Firebase guide did not include it.

Comment: you're still reading the entire document from Firestore, if that matters. You are consuming the bandwidth of the full document with this read on the client.

Comment: Yes, but at least the client need not loop through the whole document to get 1 single field data.

Comment: Animal animal = document.toObject(Animal); then animal.getName() or in js const animal = document.data(); then animal.name, use models!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase allows a few ways to query like an RDBMS database. And these are very handy too.  **Try the Where clause. It returns a single document but u can add multiple filters.** [image: Example:]
[check for more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#web-version-9_11)

Answer (score -2):

try this code:

```
//set a global variable
dataList: Array<any>;


const dataCollection = firebase.firestore().collection('data');
dataCollection.get(query => {
query.forEach(docs => {
this.dataList.push({id: doc.id, data:doc.data()});
  })
})
```