# Retrieve Contact Data From Firestore Efficiently Using A Query

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-contacts

My requirement is, when a user Mr.ABC install the app it will take all the contacts of the user and save to Firebase Firestore. And when another user Mr.XYZ installs the app in his device, it will take all contacts of XYZ and save to Firebase. Likewise whoever installs the app it will take the contacts and save to Firebase Firestore. Now my read operation should be, Mr.ABC will type XYZ number in EditText and in firebase, I have to look into XYZ contact details and find out ABC's number and get the name in which XYZ saved in his contact. So when ABC type XYZ number, ABC can able to find out in which name XYZ saved ABC's number. Please help me in which structure I should save the contacts in firebase and in how can I read the data. I would like to know the efficient way to do this. As I'm not good with database, helping me with exact code will be much more helpful. Please help.[image]

I have tried the below code but only 800 contacts are stored to Firestore instead of 2500, moreover i'm not sure the db structure I'm using is right or wrong. I have zero knowledge on DB.

```java
    private void doUploadContactstoCloud() {
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait we are configuring your request ...");
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.show();
        listContacts = new ContactPresenter(this).fetchAllContacts();
        int j = listContacts.size();

        Log.d("sizejhfg",j+"");

        double size = listContacts.size();
        double ind = 0;
        Map<String, Object> contact = new HashMap<>();
        // Get a new write batch
        WriteBatch batch = db.batch();
        for (Contact con : listContacts) {
            for (int i = 0; i < con.numbers.size(); i++) {
                String number = formatnum(con.numbers.get(i).number);
                if (number != null) {
                    if (!number.equals("0") && number.length() < 5) {

                        Map<String, Object> contactnumber = new HashMap<>();
                        contactnumber.put("name", con.name);
                        contactnumber.put("number", number);
                        contact.put(number,contactnumber);
                        DocumentReference item = db.collection(tonumber).document(number);
                        batch.set(item,contactnumber);
                        ind++;
                        if(ind==500){
                            doCommit(batch);
                            batch=db.batch();
                            ind=0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //dialog.setProgress((int) (ind / size) * 100);
        }
        if(ind>0){
            doCommit(batch);
        }
        prefManager.setisContactUpload(true);
        doDismissDialog();
    }`
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is too broad.

Comment: added the code I tried

Comment: Try to use: addSuccessListener & addFailureListener when adding data and committing batch. You can use it to debug, and finds out the problem.

Comment: See [Add data to Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data). I use custom object with a call to add (not set), which makes firestore auto-generate document ID for you.

Comment: Yosi and Ron didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible answer to your question -

Firstly, the Firestore Database structure. I will call it the db structure for now. Here is a template that might work for you -

```
c- Contacts
   d- +1 9999999999 //ABC's Phone No.
      f- +1 0000000000 : XYZ's Number // XYZ's Saved Name in ABC's Contacts and his phone no.
      f- +1 1111111111 : LMN's Number // LMN's Saved Name in ABC's Contacts and his phone no.
   d- +1 0000000000 //XYZ's Phone No.
      f- +1 9999999999 : ABC's Number //ABC's Saved Name in XYZ's Contacts and his phone no.
      f- +1 1111111111 : LMN's Number // LMN's Saved Name in XYZ's Contacts and his phone no.
```

Secondly, here is the code that I think will work for adding and querying the db -

```
Map<String, Object> contacts = new HashMap<>();
contacts.put("+1 0000000000", "XYZ's Number");
contacts.put("+1 1111111111", "LMN's Number");

db.collection("contacts").document("+1 9999999999")
        .set(contacts)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
            }
        });
```

EDITED this part for a more efficient query -

```
db.collections("contacts").document("+1 9999999999").get(EditTextEnteredNumber)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snap : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    Log.d(TAG, snap.getId() + " => " + snap.getData());
                    TextViewContactName.setText(snap.getData());
                }
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps!!

Sources

- Official Cloud Firestore Docs - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/?utm_source=studio
- SO Article - [How to access a specific field from Cloud FireStore Firebase in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48312485/how-to-access-a-specific-field-from-cloud-firestore-firebase-in-swift)

Comment: thanks for giving it a try but here, it is not only going to be just two users and those two users wont be having 2 contacts.  it is going to be one million users, each with 5000 contacts. Kindly update your answer.

Comment: if I follow this, I need to take whole contacts of a user. For example if a user is having 5000 contacts, just to take one contact details, I need to fetch all 5000 contacts. Do you think is there any way I can get only one contact what I what? I think it ls there in the way we save the data ie data structure in db.

Comment: According to the docs, Firestore doesn't get all the data in a query, it gets only the one that is being queried. I have limited knowledge in this part and am very sorry I could not be of much help. Nevertheless, I shall try gathering more info on this and hopefully edit my answer by tomorrow or day after.

Comment: Try checking out all the link in the Firestore Docs, starting with this one - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data

Comment: Edited the answer for a more efficient query - hope it helps!!