# How can i retrieve one specific field from Firestore collection's document without doing in it via the uid document?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, collections, document

as I mentioned in the title, im trying to pull data from a specific field, the idea is the user is typing a certain number in the search bar, if the number (car license number) exist the user can contact the car owner.

what im trying to do is checking this field throughout all users.[image]

my current code :

```
   func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchText == "" {
        
        carNumberLbl.text = ""
    }else {
        getData ()
    }
}

func getData (){
    let docRef = db.collection("Users").document("2MHOob4kgh8JOu6UXxfb")
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let carNumber = document.get("car_license")
            self.carNumberLbl.text = carNumber as! String
            print(carNumber)
        }else
        {
            print("Couldn't find data")
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution!**

```
func getDataSpecificField (){
    
    db.collection("Users").whereField("car_license", isEqualTo: self.searchBarCars.text!)
        .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let carNumber = document.get("car_license") as! String
                    self.carNumberLbl.text =  carNumber
                    
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) has good examples look at`whereField`

Comment: thanks for your comment, i tried that whereField method, it didn't work out for me though.

Comment: Please share what you did with whereField so we would know what's wrong. More details on how to use it:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#swift

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access a specific field from Cloud FireStore Firebase in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48312485/how-to-access-a-specific-field-from-cloud-firestore-firebase-in-swift)

Comment: thanks for your help guys, i found a solution and updated it on my original question.

Comment: @ShyAttoun Good job on finding the solution to your own question. Could you please post your answer as a formal answer to help other users that have a similar problem?