# How to access a single field in firebase doc in ionic app

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to access a single field in a firebase document without downloading the entire doc.

Usecase:
I have a comments page and a comments collection in firebase. I need to know how many comments are in there without downloading them all. There is a doc with a field commentCount, which is updated every time a new comment is posted, and an array of all comments. I want to access the field commentCount and read its value.

```
this.angularFireStore.firestore.collection('comments/' + id + '/commentCount').get().then(col => {
      console.log(col);
    });
```

I have tried this, but it returns an undefinded.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: Cloud Firestore always reads a complete document. There is no way to read just a single field from a document. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47477449/209103

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that `commentCount` is not a list, therefore it has to be [Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#documents) and not a [Collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model).

Try this:

```
this.angularFireStore.firestore.document('comments/' + id).valueChanges()
 .subscribe(comment => console.log(comment.commentCount));
```

Also, I wouldn't place the comment count in the your `comments` list, what happens if your delete this specific comment?